# How does Intel PROSet attempt to calculate the length of a cable, and why does it work on some adaptors and not others?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I've got the 'wired' version of the Intel  PROSet Adapter configuration utility installed when installing 10Gbe cards on my desktop. While messing with it, and shortly after needing to reseat an ethernet cable connected to my onboard gigabit adaptor for performance issues (It was doing fast, not gigabit ethernet speeds), it informed me that my cable length was 255m (which is implausible, since I think I would notice a giant roll of ethernet behind my desk)

I'm running all the adaptors on windows 11 in this case (though I believe the system on the other end has very similar network hardware and software)

[image]

On a second run, after reseating the cable, it measured a more realistic 4m

[image]

Interestingly, while I can run the cable tests on a (modern?), low end [I219-V](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/82186/intel-ethernet-connection-i219v.html) - Its not available on my 'higher' end, though older [X540-T2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58954/intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x540t2.html). I also tried it with an [82579V](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52963/intel-82579v-gigabit-ethernet-phy.html) which proset wouldn't manage at all.

How *does* the intel driver detect cable length (and further down, cable quality and integrity) - and why wouldn't it work on my 10Gbps cards?

Comment: My guess would be resistance or some other means of electrical measurement involving passing electricity from one end to the other and checking whether a specified value has changed or is within a certain parameter

Comment: Kinda curious to why its 'restricted' to certain cards as well, but I'd think hammering it open would be abusive ;)

Comment: If it can time a packet, 1 Ft. / nSec.   ( one foot per nano(10**-9) second )